Updating Laravel 10 to version 11
I'm trying to run my app after updating Laravel from version 10 to 11. I made some changes in composer.json and updated my entire project to Laravel 11. However, when I try to execute my index, I get the following message:

Call to undefined method ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous()

I'm working in XAMPP and I updated my PHP to version 8.2. I didn't make any changes to the core code that would cause this message to appear.
This error is in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 680.
Has anyone else encountered this error?
Update:
I attach my composer.json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "illuminate/support": "*",
        "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "milon/barcode": "^11.0",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "*",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "*",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.4",
        "wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "0.12.2.3",
        "yoeunes/toastr": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.8",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}


Did you update PHP for both your CLI and your web?

@ChrisHaas thanks for your response. i think that i didn´t updated php cli in xamp.. Only Update php version. How can i do it?

Did you look at the upgrade notes before doing all this? Upgrading To 11.0 From 10.x

XAMPP on Windows or Linux

@RiggsFolly thanks for your response. Yes, i read it

@RiggsFolly in windows

Then do >php --version from a command Prompt window to see what version of PHP is being used by the CLI

@RiggsFolly PHP 8.2.17 (cli)

@RiggsFolly i updated my question with composer.sjon

Can you also make a file in your web with just <?php phpinfo(); , visit that URL in your browser and post the version reported there

@ChrisHaas ouch... in php_info my version it´s PHP Version 8.1.6

How did you upgrade you XAMPP's PHP?

@RiggsFolly i downloaded php 8.2.17 from oficial php page, and unzip this file, paste php folder into c:\xampp (Initial, php folder into xampp, i rename it to php_old) paste any .dll into new php folder, because apache not run because not found libraries, and in new php folder paste php.ini from older folder. In resume this it´s steps

Maybe worth checking this post to see what you may have missed and others on that question

@RiggsFolly thanks for your help. I read this thread and redo all, and in php_info, return 8.1... i don´t understand

Dont think you properly changed the Param in http.conf that links the PHP to Apache, so you got the old version

@RiggsFolly not, i solve my problem with your help. My problem was php version, i´m trying to use php nts, and i need php ts version

Ahh that old problem. Yes that makes sense
